# XGBoost Package Failing to Load in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, xgboost

I currently am trying to use XGBoost in a python project inside of PyCharm and it always will say that it is installed as is shown here, [Showing Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npi5E.png),
and it shows confirmation here at the bottom but it is not listed in the [package list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pZb4.png). Then it is not available for use in my program. Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Confusion is probably caused by [PY-29611](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29611) issue - PyCharm reported failed package installations as successful. The problem with PyCharm UI should be fixed in 2018.1.2, meanwhile, try to install XGBoost from the terminal to discover the real problem behind the failed installation.